# MX Notify Control PHP error on extension page

Tags: mx-title-control

Using MX Notify Control 2.4.6 in a project on EE 2.9.3 . Calling the Add-ons extensions page gives a error. Server runs on PHP 5.5 or 5.6

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class Mx_notify_control_ext in /.../expressionengine/third_party/mx_notify_control/ext.mx_notify_control.php on line 62

The extension seems to work, but the error should be. Is the code not PHP 5.5 compatible?

Comment: hello, could u please try reupload this file - https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-notify-control/blob/master/system/expressionengine/third_party/mx_notify_control/ext.mx_notify_control.php

Comment: Ok. good. Working on the new version (rewritten it from 0). Hope to release it in next 3-4 weeks. I add my answer bellow. Please confirm it just to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did [quick update](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-notify-control/)(v 2.4.7). It should remove this error.